# How can I check the version of packages to be installed with apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, apt

After running `apt-get upgrade`, I get a list of the packages that will be upgraded. I would like to know the version number for one of these packages. (Not the current one but the one that will be installed).

How do I get the version number of the packages to be installed?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
apt-cache show <packagename>
```

should include the full version numbers.

---

Update as this answer has recently seen upvotes:

With more recent releases you can use `apt list <packagename>` to get a display of the most pertinent information (version, installation status) in one line  or `apt show <packagename>` for fuller information as provided by `apt-cache`. The other commands (and `aptitude` too if installed) still work as before.

Be sure to heed the warning emitted to stderr¹ if you pipe the output of apt to other commands, if you use it in a script or documentation that is intended to be around for a while.

<sup>[1] “apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.”</sup>

Answer (score 18):

If you just want the version info without the description and such, use `apt-cache policy` instead of `apt-cache show`.